# Function to check for all the files active this year

Tags: php, sonata

I am getting an error with my `PHP` function on the `sonata` framework

```
public function getIsActiveThisYear(): bool
{
    $now = Carbon::now();
    return $this->whereBetween($endDate, [
        Carbon::$now->startOfYear(),
        Carbon::$now->endOfYear(),
    ])|| $this->whereBetween($endDate, [
        Carbon::$now->startOfYear(),
        Carbon::$now->endOfYear(),
    ]);
}
```

This is an error i get when testing my code

> Error: Call to undefined method

Comment: Normally an error message llke that would contain more information, like the function name that is causing the issue and a line number in the code where the error happens!! Do you have a complete error message

Comment: $now is not used. Carbon::$now looks wrong, maybe do $now->startOfYear()? Or which method is undefined?

Comment: So the class you are in `App\Entity\Project` does not have a method called `whereBetween` I dont know Sonata, but I would expect that to be a method on some database/Model class

Comment: what would be the alternative to find all files actively being used this year to substitute whereBetween. the link to the carbon library is this https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ @RiggsFolly

Comment: Your SECOND Question : I dont think its a Carbon issue, it is a where does the database access code live issue i.e. you are using the wrong class to call the `whereBetween` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created the variable `$now` as a Carbon DateTime, so you dont need the `Carbon::` in front of it when you use it.

```
public function getIsActiveThisYear(): bool
{
    $now = Carbon::now();
    return $this->whereBetween($endDate, [
        $now->startOfYear(),
        $now->endOfYear(),
    ])|| $this->whereBetween($endDate, [
        $now->startOfYear(),
        $now->endOfYear(),
    ]);
}
```

> Also you use `$this->whereBetween($endDate,` twice, maybe one should be a start Date?? But thats a bit of a guess :)

Comment: i have updated my question with the error i am receiving @RiggsFolly

Comment: Actually, you have totally changed your question into another question. THAT is not sensible. If you now have another question ask another question